# [UITabBarController setPassedData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I will give a outline of the program below but, when pushing a new view controller (not a tab bar view) I select a value on a stepper and then click a button to go back. I am trying to send the stepper value to the FirstViewController from FilterViewController.

The program:

App loads on `FirstViewController` which is the first tab of a tab bar controller, in the top left of the screen is a button (magnifying glass) which opens up FilterViewController.

FilterViewController has a stepper, a label (which displays the value of the stepper) and a button. You click the button, it saves to a variable the value of the stepper and I need to pass it to FirstViewController.

**FirstViewController.h (the property im accessing from FilterViewController)**

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *passedData;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *passedData;
```

**FirstViewController.m (code that pushes the new view controller, the property is also synthesised in the implementation)**

```
- (IBAction)searchOptions:(id)sender {
    FilterViewController *ctrl = [[FilterViewController alloc] init];
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:ctrl.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:nil];

    self.filterViewController = ctrl;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.filterViewController animated:NO];

}
```

**FilterViewController.m (code that saves the value and passes it to FirstViewController)**

```
- (IBAction)backToMap:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    FirstViewController *fvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
    fvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    self.firstViewData = fvc;

    fvc.passedData = @"yo";

    //firstViewData.passedData = @"hello test test test";

    [self presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When it gets to the execution of this it crashes saying: *[UITabBarController setPassedData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance*

Comment: fvc is a UITabBarController, not a FirstViewController.

Comment: I set it up that way as when I just did a normal transition I got a black screen showing, so I went about it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code. You are giving `TabBarController` as identifier for FirstViewController.  May be you are mistaken

```
FirstViewController *fvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"]; // Here check the identifier
fvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

self.firstViewData = fvc;
```

Comment: Ahh but, now my UIToolbar has disappeared

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean that the crash happens in following line of your code

```
    fvc.passedData = @"yo";
```

you may want to check that fvc is indeed a FirstViewController `NSLog("%@", fvc);` i.e. was the class in IB changed from a UIViewController to a FirstViewController ?

Comment: Hey, I think the crash must happen on that line. When doing the NSLog it errors out in the IDE saying `Implicit conversion of a non-objective-c pointer type 'char *' to type 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC`

Comment: Double check in IB that you have a 'MainStoryboard'; and check that 'TabBarController' is indeed of the class 'FirstViewController'.

Comment: @Dirk-WillemvanGulik The class is obviously wrong - just look at the exception message, it states it's `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Hey - better to assist with fishing than catch & fry them fishes :)

Comment: @Dirk-WillemvanGulik My tab bar controller has the class TabBarController then the children (different tabs) have the classes like FirstViewController etc, is that right? The xib is MainStoryboard.storyboard

Comment: Right - but what you are missing is that your instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: is pointing to the wrong thing. So you need to make sure that your FirstViewController has a sensible name - and point to that. And will then find that your TabBarController springs to live.